# How can I update a SQL Column base on SELECT Subquery with condition and join?

Tags: sql-server, database

Assume that I have 2 tables as below:

1. Table 1 (Products) contains all information about products

[Table Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk1f7.png)

- ProID: represent Product ID primary key
- UnitType: Unit measure of product
- Pkg: Package quantity of product per box

2. Table 2 (Products_stock) contains all information about products quantity and Number of packages

[Product_stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcZn2.png)

- NoPkg: total number of packages of each products calulated by (Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / Products.Pkg and Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % Products.Pkg and some more conditions)

### Purposes & Problems

I want to update every row in the NoPkg column everytime I make a change to Qty_on_hand in Products_stock table or Pkg in Products table. I planned to accomplished this by using trigger on delete, insert, update but I'm struggling with sql statement

I have try this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Products_stock SET
    NoPkg = (
        SELECT (CASE WHEN (dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) = 0 THEN '' WHEN ((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) <> 0) AND ((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) > 0))) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes ' ELSE '' END)
        FROM dbo.Products_stock
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.Products_stock.product_id = dbo.Products.ProductID
        WHERE dbo.Products.ProductID = dbo.Products_stock.product_id
    )
```

I got the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My question is how can I fix this? And any suggestions which are better ways to update Qty_on_hand or NoPkg rather than using trigger? Because I am new to this and kind of a self taught and I don't have experiences on developing software before.

Comment: I want to update all rows of NoPkg in Products_stock...

Comment: This is my first time posting something on Stack Overflow with zero experiences. I don't know what to do, How to vote, follow.. :D

Comment: Thats why I told you - however its worth reading through the FAQ for the site as it explains how things are meant to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly want to update the entire table each time, which is not best practice, then first build the query which produces the correct results, then convert it to an update.

Before we start, its best practice for many reasons to use table aliases in queries and for this sort of update they are required. So I have added them.

Assuming your query is working you would do this as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg = 0 THEN ''
    WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0 AND dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg > 0 THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes '
    ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Products_stock PS
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products P ON P.ProductId = PS.product_id;
```

Converts to:

```
UPDATE PS SET
    NoPkg = 
        CASE
        WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg = 0 THEN ''
        WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0 AND dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg > 0 THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes '
        ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Products_stock PS
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products P ON P.ProductId = PS.product_id;
```

What I would suggest is having a trigger on each table and limiting your updates to rows changed e.g.

```
-- Inside trigger on dbo.Products_stock
UPDATE PS SET NoPkg = 
  CASE
  WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg = 0 THEN ''
  WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0 AND dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg > 0 THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes '
  ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Products_stock PS
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products P ON P.ProductId = PS.product_id
WHERE PS.product_id in (SELECT product_id from Inserted UNION ALL SELECT product_id from Deleted);

-- Inside trigger on dbo.Products
UPDATE PS SET NoPkg = 
  CASE
  WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg = 0 THEN ''
  WHEN dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0 AND dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg > 0 THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes '
  ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Products_stock PS
LEFT JOIN dbo.Products P ON P.ProductId = PS.product_id
WHERE P.product_id in (SELECT ProductId from Inserted UNION ALL SELECT ProductId from Deleted)
```

I wonder whether you need a `LEFT JOIN` or whether an `INNER JOIN` would be more suitable.

Note: I would only update `NoPkg` in a trigger if you have a very good reason to, otherwise I would calculate it in a query when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and suggestion! It works as expected.  I use trigger to update it instead of calculating it in a query because I think it's too long when combined with other statements and I also use it many places in my application

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE PS
SET NoPkg = (CASE WHEN (dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) = 0 THEN '' WHEN ((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) <> 0) AND ((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) > 0))) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes + ' + CONVERT([nvarchar](4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg) +' ' + Products.UnitType WHEN((dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg <> 0) AND(dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand % dbo.Products.Pkg = 0)) THEN CONVERT([nvarchar] (4), dbo.Products_stock.Qty_on_hand / dbo.Products.Pkg) +' boxes ' ELSE '' END)
FROM dbo.Products_stock PS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products P ON PS.product_id = P.ProductID
```